# Add column with repeated numbers per group

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to add a new column with a 3-number repeat 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3 until the end of each group (Chr) within the data frame. This would be easy if all the groups can be divided by 3, but I am not sure how to do this when the group length is divisible by 2. What happens with the last repeat within each group?

```
original <- data.frame(Chr=c("chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr2","chr2","chr2","chr2","chr2","chr3"),
           value=c(1,3,1,3,5,6,3,1,3,5,0),
           seq=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6))

modified <- data.frame(Chr=c("chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1","chr2","chr2","chr2","chr2","chr2","chr3"),
                       value=c(1,3,1,3,5,6,3,1,3,5,0),
                       seq=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6),
                       rep=c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1))
```

Comment: Why do you post the same question again?

Comment: different question

Comment: Absolutely same! Except that you want to sum up values in the previous question, but not in this question. The grouping process is identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `gl()` function:

```
library(dplyr)

original %>% 
  mutate(rep = as.integer(gl(n(),3,n())), .by=Chr)
```

```
    Chr value seq group
1  chr1     1   1     1
2  chr1     3   2     1
3  chr1     1   3     1
4  chr1     3   4     2
5  chr1     5   5     2
6  chr2     6   1     1
7  chr2     3   2     1
8  chr2     1   3     1
9  chr2     3   4     2
10 chr2     5   5     2
11 chr3     0   6     1
```